# ModuleNotFoundError but the module name exists in one of the directories in sys.path

Tags: python, path, package, sys

**The issue**

I've pip installed a library called `disagree` which installed and upgraded without any issues, confirming that the latest version had been successfully installed.

When running `import disagree` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'disagree'
```

**Identifying what's causing the issue**

Section 6.1.2 in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages says that when a module is imported, if it is not in the `sys.builtin_module_names`, then it proceeds to search for it in the file paths specified in `sys.path`.

When I run `sys.path` I get:

```
['', '/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/lib/python38.zip',
'/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/lib/python3.8', 
'/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/oliverprice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', 
'/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Indeed, looking into `'/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages'` I can see the module that I've installed. However, it only has the `.dist-info` file for the package, not the actual package folder. I.e. rather than

```
name
name-version.dist-info
```

the only thing present is:

```
disagree-1.2.6.dist-info
```

So it looks like there is no actual package in there, and just the `.dist-info`. Specifically, this is a snapshot of what is in there:

```
defusedxml
defusedxml-0.6.0.dist-info
dill
dill-0.3.4.dist-info
disagree-1.2.6.dist-info
distutils-precedence.pth
docutils
docutils-0.16.dist-info
easy_install.py
entrypoints-0.3.dist-info
```

**Questions**

1. Is this the reason it is failing to import? If not, what is the reason?
2. If so, why has this happened?

Comment: Yes. By default `pip` will install into `site-packages`. Python itself really doesn't care about the `dist-info`s and only wants the actual packages. You'll need to either copy it over to there, or change your `sys.path` back to the default. You probably did this from installing conda which then changed your python configuration. If you want to temporarily disable it look in your `.bashrc` and comment out those lines.

Comment: @EricJin 1. If I have to copy it over there, will other people be experiencing the same issue when installing this library, or is it to do with how my computer has been configured? 2. What do you mean by changing my `sys.path` back to default?

Comment: The reason for the first question is because I built the library, so if my build process has been incorrectly implemented I'd like to address that.

Comment: I was having the same problem when I installed conda. Your package manager isn't really broken, you just have your package locations set to somewhere else. To change the `sys.path` back to default you'll probably need to look at your `.bashrc` to remove the lines near the end with the conda initialization stuff.

Comment: @EricJin Will give that a try. Once I've removed the lines will I need to run anything in order to get the `sys.path` back to default?

Comment: Also any idea where it is? Google searches say it's in the home directory but when I run `ls -a ~/.` it isn't in there

Comment: I found the file in `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: That works too if you installed it as root. All you have to do is open a new terminal window (reboot wasn't necessary for me but you might want to try it). You should see your terminal prompt go back to normal.

Comment: @EricJin there wasn't actually anything in `.bashrc` indicating any conda initialisation so I ultimately just ended up copying the library folder into the `site-packages` directory. That fixes the issue as expected, but isn't a long term solution really.

Comment: You could try temporarily undoing what you just did and then `pip install`ing it again. It should probably fix. What's the header when you type `python<whatever version>` in your shell? (The three lines that say `Python <version>` and the copyright notice and help text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue here. This solution below worked for me.

First of all, check the version of python that you have (must be between python3.8 and 3.10 (included). No python3.7 and python3.11 as I understand.

To check it do this in your notebook/python:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If it matches with the 3.8-3.10 range, then you're ok and skip this step, otherwise you may need to do (in the terminal):

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.8
source venv/bin/activate
```

Let's now install this library from source so that we have the needed source files. Run this in a terminal:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/o-P-o/disagree.git
cd disagree
# requirements fixed
pip install numpy pandas mathx scipy tqdm
# install this
pip install .
```

Now you should be able to import disagree, but with a twist:

```py
from disagree import disagree
# or for example
from disagree.disagree.agreements import BiDisagreements
```

Please let me know if this works for you.
I will be doing a pull request to fix this library.

Martino